# VBA - applying bullet-point style from the slide master to selected text boxes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In VBA for PowerPoint, I want to applying bullet-point style from the slide master to selected text boxes. Is this even possible? I've been searching the internet for ages on this, and can't seem to find anything even close.

I can select or place text boxes on the slide in VBA, but I want to use the bullet-point layout as defined on the slide master - I just don't know how to select it, and once selected I assume I use the Shape.PickUp and Apply (or is there another way of doing this that I haven't thought of?)

Any help greatly appreciated.

David.

Comment: IGNORE. As is so often the case - you ask a question and then work out the answer. For those that want to know, Shape(3) is the bullet-point list object on the slide master...

Comment: Please provide the solution on the answer section. You can answer your question. Anyone else come across this same issue they can see your solution.